# In React native IOS getting "RCTBridge required dispatch_snyc to load RCTDevLoadingView This may lead to deadlocks."

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

As i reload the appliaction after closing it after some progress screen just gone blank and this warning is coming " RCTBridge required dispatch_snyc to load RCTDevLoadingView This may lead to deadlocks. " please help me out..